# Developing toLower/toUppercase function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm suppposed to develop a function which given a char *, returns a new char (it should not share memory with this the one its given) and, convert lowerCase tu UpperCase and viceversa. I have understood I should add a '\0' (on the new char *, called 'retorno') character once I finish iterating on the char * given by the function ('palabra'). The output I'm getting is garbage; example of current output:

```
Prueba Invertir Case de palabra 1 -> ERROR salida incorrecta
    Parametros de entrada: 
    Se esperaba: 
    Se recibio:  Э§§§§нннcЙtp
----------------------------------------------
Prueba Invertir Case de palabra 2 -> ERROR salida incorrecta
    Parametros de entrada: hola
    Se esperaba: HOLA
    Se recibio:  ЭЭЭЭЭ§§§§
----------------------------------------------
Prueba Invertir Case de palabra 3 -> ERROR salida incorrecta
    Parametros de entrada: Write in C
    Se esperaba: wRITE IN c
    Se recibio:  ЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ§§§§
```

This is my code, the question is, HOW CAN I ADD that \0 character to "retorno"? Is that the only problem I'm facing???

```
char* invertirCase(char* palabra)
{

    char* retorno = new char[largo(palabra)+1];

    int i = 0;
    while (palabra[i] != '\0') {

        if (palabra[i]>= 'A' && (palabra[i] )<= 'Z') {
            palabra[i] += 32;
        }

        if (palabra[i] >= 'a' && palabra[i] <= 'z') {
            palabra[i] -= 32;
        }
        i++;

    }
    retorno [i] = '\0';
    return retorno;

}
```

I re designed totally the solution and now it worked! If someone suggests improvements, there would be more than welcome !

```
int i = 0;
char c;
do
{
  c = palabra[i];
  if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )
    c += 'a' - 'A';
  else if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
    c -= 'a' - 'A';

  retorno[i] = c;
  i++;
} while( c != '\0');`
```

Comment: I take it this is for exercise purposes only? Because there are *so* many things wrong with this... not using `<string>`, not using smart pointers *if* you *have* to allocate memory yourself, assuming ASCII-7 charset...

Comment: Your code never writes anything into `retorno`

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT time to use your debugger to step through your code and see how your variables change in real time. You can add `'\0'` to the end of your `char *` by just saying `retorno[x] = '\0';`, where `x` is the index after the last valid character in your array.

Comment: Hi DevSolar! It´s academic purpose only indeed; I cannot use library functions such from  C/C++ (such as strcpy, toupper, tolower etc.).

Comment: You created this new array named "retorno", put something in it. You are just allocating it and returning it. Add some good content to it as advised in problem description and indeed the \0 in the end.

Comment: Hi @JohnFilleau ! I´ve added as you suggested, but still it´s outputing "garbage", Im learning to code; I do not know almost nothing of coding, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Juan, there are a number of other things wrong with your code. Please read the other comments about not modifying `retorno`.

Comment: Also please step through with a debugger. That was the MOST important part of my original comment. This code is not doing what you expect it to, and using your debugger will give you valuable visibility.

Comment: Juan, don't put code in comments. It's ugly and unreadable. Edit your question and add it there. Highlight the block of code and click the `{ }` button to enclose it in backticks so it displays as a code block.

Comment: You would skip converting alternate characters as you increment index variable 2 times and could lead to more errors

Comment: Here's a hint - every other character and `retorno` needs some use.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Thank you sir, Im a rookie on this! I edited and updated; I m reading the rest of the suggestions!

Comment: @DevSolar Sir, the problem is that is a restriction from my college, I cannot use those functions because otherwise I will not get any points.... anyway thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález: And I am telling you, that course at your college *stinks*. You may tell them I said that. More importantly, tell them that [Kate Gregory said that at CppCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk&list=FLe5cxHN7iNybQISW1NIY_QQ). This "C++ course" is *wasting your time and energy*, and not teaching you C++. There is literally *nothing* in that code that's C++, except that it says "new" instead of "malloc".

Comment: @DevSolar True that, only c++ I could see is "new". Haha Thanks for CppCon link

Comment: @DevSolar LOL!! Anyway do not worry, I´ll figure out how to deliver this exercise :). I do not have other choice.

Comment: Your code does a very good job of modifying `palabra`, but the purpose was to write to `retorno`.

Comment: @mSatyam: As a lecturer, I'd probably throw such an example of "homegrown" at the wall and use it as a punching bag to show what all a naïve implementation can get wrong. Show an EBCDIC code table to show the futility of character arithmetics, and that you shouldn't have "magic numbers" in your code (the `32`). Point out that resource allocation should only happen in constructors, so the destructor can release the resource again (RAII). That identifiers should be in English, because at some point someone else *will* look at your code.

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález On a side note: get in the habit of declaring any parameters that you don't intend to modify as `const`.  Had `palabra` been declared as `const char* palabra` then your assignments to `palabra[i]` would fail to compile, and that might have gotten you to think about assigning to `retorno[i]` instead, which is the solution to your garbage problem.

Comment: Suggestions on the edited code: 1) Use English for identifiers. 2) I'd use `retorno[ i++ ] = c` instead of doing the increment on a line of its own. 3) Another "shortcut" would be to have `while ( ( c = palabra[i] ) )` at the top of the loop. (Assignment evaluates to the value assigned, so you can assign the first character to `c` before even entering the loop without having to duplicate code, and check if it's non-null in the same step.) 4) I'd add a big fat comment that this code **assumes** ASCII-7 encoding. Even better, have it cry bloody murder if it encounters a value > `0x7f`...

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked was:
char* invertirCase(char* palabra)
{ 
    //Retorno un nuevo string con el case Invertido y considerando el '\0'.

```
char* retorno = new char[largo(palabra)+1];

int i = 0;
char c;
do
{
    c = palabra[i];
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        c += 'a' - 'A';
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        c -= 'a' - 'A';

    retorno[i] = c;
    i++;
} while (c != '\0');
return retorno;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

He verificado su código. Si esta función 'largo (palabra)' calcula la longitud, entonces el código debe ser el siguiente:

```
        char* invertirCase(char* palabra)
       {

       char* retorno = new char[largo(palabra)+1];
       int i = 0;
       while (palabra[i] != '\0') {

           if (palabra[i]>= 'A' && (palabra[i] )<= 'Z') {
               retorno [i]=palabra[i] + 32;
             }

           else if (palabra[i] >= 'a' && palabra[i] <= 'z') {
                retorno [i]= palabra[i] - 32;
             }
           else
                retorno [i]= palabra[i] ;

           i++;

       }
       return retorno;

       }
```

Comment: Please answer in English. StackOverflow is intended to not only answer the immediate question of the poster, but to have the answers remain for others with similar problems to find. By not using English in your answer, you are sharply reducing the overall usefulness of your answer.